# Trying to install lighttpd with macports, but get 'upgrade openssl failed'?

Tags: mac, macports, openssl, lighttpd

I want to install lighttpd with macports, but:

```
$ sudo port install lighttpd
--->  Computing dependencies for openssl
--->  Building openssl
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Log for openssl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade openssl failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

The tail of the log says:

```
:info:build collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
:info:build make[4]: *** [link_a.darwin] Error 1
:info:build make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/work/openssl-1.0.0e-i386'
:info:build make[3]: *** [do_darwin-shared] Error 2
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/work/openssl-1.0.0e-i386'
:info:build make[2]: *** [libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib] Error 2
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/work/openssl-1.0.0e-i386'
:info:build make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/work/openssl-1.0.0e-i386/crypto'
:info:build make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/work/openssl-1.0.0e-i386'
:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/work/openssl-1.0.0e-i386" && /usr/bin/make -w all " returned error 2
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for openssl): org.macports.install org.macports.build org.macports.destroot
:notice:build Log for openssl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_openssl/openssl/main.log
```

Any idea how I can upgrade openssl?

Comment: Fixed it with: `sudo port clean openssl` then `sudo port -d install openssl`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend moving from macports to [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which is better maintained and less problematic regarding dependencies.  In addition you never need to use sudo with homebrew:

`brew install lighttpd`

Answer (score 0):

Midwire,

The idea to run away from port is not always a solution to the existing problem.

The `-d` switch adds a LOT of debugging information to the installation process, so if you don't want to see that, omit the `-d` switch.  But cleaning and reinstalling the failed package worked miracles.